# Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type LoginViewModel found. A environmentObject for LoginViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swiftui, runtime-error, environmentobject

When trying to display all my accounts in my database by pressing a button in `LeaderboardScreen`, I get this error while running the program. I don't know why as I'm sure that I have correctly implemented an `@EnviromentObject`. Here is how my `ContentView` looks like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLoggedIn = false
    @StateObject var accountListVM = AccountListViewModel()
    @StateObject var loginVM = LoginViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var userViewModel = UserViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        
           LoginScreen()
                .environmentObject(accountListVM)
                .environmentObject(loginVM)
        }
      
    }
}
```

And this is my `LeaderboardScreen`, where I get my error:

```
import SwiftUI


struct LeaderboardScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var accountlistVM: AccountListViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var loginVM: LoginViewModel
  

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button("See leaderboard") {
                accountlistVM.getAllAccounts()
               
                
            }
            .padding()
            if loginVM.isAuthenticated && accountlistVM.accounts.count > 0 {
                List(accountlistVM.accounts, id: \.id) { account in
                    HStack{
                        Text("\(account.name)")
                        Text("Total counts: \(account.cookiesCount)")
                    }
                    
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            } else {
                Text("Login to see your account")
            }
            }               
                
        }      
        
    }
```

To be more specific, here is where the error is located:
 `if loginVM.isAuthenticated && accountlistVM.accounts.count > 0 {`

Comment: probably a typo, in `ContentView` change `LoginScreen()` to `LeaderboardScreen()`